# Why does my SP take 7 seconds to run in SQL Server but MS Access takes 37 seconds to generate a report using it?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2016

I timed the execution of a report in MS Access and noticed that it takes about 37 seconds to run. This seems strange to me because it is much faster to run the SP alone in SQL Server (7 seconds). What is Access doing that adds 30 seconds of execution time when using this SP in a pass-through query? Are there any settings in Access I can toggle to reduce whatever is making it take so long?

Comment: is some network involved? I would also consider using a view in Access, as they can often run better then a stored procedure. But, as the answer below notes, hard to tell without more information about the report, and is some network between access and sql server.

Comment: @J.D. your link is giving a "Page not found" error

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Sorry something weird must've happened and the link got changed (deleted my old comment). Please use [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) to upload your execution plans and then link them in your Post. Does your procedure have parameters?

Comment: @J.D. no it doesn't use any parms. I pasted the XML of my plan into that link but it gave this error: `The text submitted is larger than 2MB. We cannot accept plans larger than 2MB at this time. Sorry. (⌣_⌣”)`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Yikes, that is already a sign you have a problem with the procedure, probably being poorly architected, if the execution plan is that big. Please upload the raw XML to something like [PasteBin.com](https://pastebin.com/) instead, and add the link to your post. I can then copy it locally to see the plan.

Comment: @J.D. there is a size limit there too :( I would need to make 18 PasteBin links to show the whole plan. Right now I'm looking at adding some indexes to speed up the query running alone in SSMS, but not sure if this will help Access execution time.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I can't use a view because a major part of my stored procedure uses a WHILE loop to iterate inventory through customer demand.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat geez, idk man. Maybe try Google Drive or feel free to email it to me in my email address located in my profile. Albert's incorrect about a View being more performant than a Stored Procedure, there's no native differences in that regard, so don't worry about that. Also, the fact you're using a `WHILE` loop is another sign of a performance bottleneck in your code. You should never need to use loops in SQL, that's an iterative approach and typically less efficient than a relational approach.

Comment: You could also just try pasting it in a code block in your Post, but I imagine it'll make the webpage take a while to load lol.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a report not only consists of running a query. There is a lot of formatting and rendering work to do. If the report has many pages, this will take some time.

Possibly the query is executed twice if you have included the number of pages on the report like "**Page 1 of 12**", because then the formatting happens twice. A first time to determine the total number of pages and a second time to insert this number into all the pages. To do this you would insert the expression `="Page " & [Page] & " of " & [Pages]` into a `TextBox`.

Use the SQL Server Profiler to see if anything unexpected happens.

A report can be very complex. It can contain groups and sub-reports, expressions in TextBoxes performing other queries by using the [DLookup Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937), ListBoxes and ComboBoxes based on other queries, etc..

Since we don't know any details about your report, it is hard to give you a better answer.

Comment: I removed the page numbering but it didn't make a difference. For my example, the report only had 2 pages anyway. The complexity is in the stored procedure only. There are no events and no visual basic behind the report. I made it from scratch, so I know for sure that the problem is the stored procedure.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat "*The complexity is in the stored procedure only.*" - Then why did you ignore my comment that asks for the relevant information to troubleshoot your procedure's performance problem? You won't find an answer on here without providing at least some of the information I mentioned.

Comment: Also, use the SQL-Server Profiler to make sure this SP is called only once per report and not, e.g., once per record or page or whatever.